# invalid function call .open() c++

Tags: c++

Not sure what is incorrect here, I believe that the function `.open()` should accept a `string`

...but some how it does not think the data returned from `getDateFormated()` i pass is of `string` type.

```
string getDateFormated()
{
int month ;
int year ;
char fileName [255];

cin >> month >> year;

sprintf(fileName, "%d_%d", year, month);

return fileName;
}




void readFile ()
{
cout << "Enter month then year: ";
string fileName = getDateFormated();

ifstream readFromFile;
readFromFile.open(fileName);
}
```

....method continues with some irrelevant branches (checking .fail etc)

**A SOLUTION** 

!!but not what im after!!

I have corrected the argument to get the program operating the way i want (by using `.c_str()`) 
...but!! i am confused as to why the first way is not working!!! because everything seems fine to me!!

```
void readFile () 
{
cout << "Enter month then year: ";
string fileName = getDateFormated();

ifstream readFromFile;
readFromFile.open(fileName.c_str());
}
```

MY ERROR MSG

> simpleIO.cpp: In function ‘void readFile()’: 
>  simpleIO.cpp:102:28:
>   error: no matching function for call to
>   ‘std::basic_ifstream::open(std::string&)’ 
>   readFromFile.open(fileName);
>                               ^ 
>  simpleIO.cpp:102:28: note: candidate is: 
>  In file included from simpleIO.cpp:9:0: 
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/fstream:541:7: note:
>   void std::b                            asic_ifstream<_CharT,
>   _Traits>::open(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [with                             _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; std::ios_base::openmode = std:
>   :_Ios_Openmode] 
>          open(const char* __s, ios_base::openmode __mode = ios_base::in)
>          ^ 
>  /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/fstream:541:7: note:
>   no known 
>   conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::string {aka
>   std::basic_string}’ to ‘c 
>                             onst
>   char*’

Comment: Are you compiling with `-std=c++11` or later?

Comment: i am compiling with gcc version 4.9.2
editor 
notepad++
cygwin terminal

Comment: I can see that, but are you passing the `-std=c++11` option when invoking gcc?

Comment: no i am not , what is that ?

Comment: the version of `open` that accepts a `std::string` was added in c++11, you will need to compile with c++11 support if you want to use it.